# Error coming up whenever I switch activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I got Android to switch activities on button press when the other activity was blank and said "Hello World". But when I specify fullscreen functionality or disable Home key access, it gives me an error when I click the button saying that my app has stopped.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
01-21 12:15:48.635      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate     I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method    android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
01-21 12:15:48.665      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11347: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
01-21 12:15:48.675      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
01-21 12:15:48.695      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11353: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
01-21 12:15:48.725      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
01-21 12:15:48.737      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9041: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
01-21 12:15:48.775      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-21 12:15:48.785      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 365: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-21 12:15:48.795      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-21 12:15:48.795      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-21 12:15:50.085      933-933/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

If you need anything else, please ask.

Comment: Is the ">" a typo after "@string/title_activity_main_activity2"? If not, then you'll need to remove it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Okay lemme go ahead and do that real quick

Comment: you should also show us your logcat stack trace so we can see what the error Android is complaining about actually is

Comment: gradle's working its magic  just on a side note I would like to thank you it seems so few people who help get thanked here :)

Comment: Removing that typo did not help. I'll get the logcat up.

Comment: Doesn't look like the full logcat.

Comment: I'm a newbie at android studio, could you tell me how to get a "full" logcat

Answer (score 0):

TO EVERYBODY WHO RESPONDED THANKS!

I think you can declare the following in your xml manifest and it should work.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```